# ¿Es una buena práctica separar HTML de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, django

Estoy escribiendo una aplicación en Django y en algunas páginas (templates) tengo pequeñas partes en JavaScript que incluyo en los HTML. Mi cuestión es: ¿es esta una buena práctica?, ¿se suele hacer así o se separa el HTML del JavaScript?

**Me refiero a código JavaScript que se usa solo en una página**. Las opciones que se me ocurren son dos y no sé qué opción es considerada como una buena práctica:

- Opción A:
  Escribir al final de la web el Javascript, dentro de las etiquetas:

  ```
  <script>
    ...
  </script>
  ```
- Opción B:
  Incluirlo y dejando el código JavaScript en un fichero separado.

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ejemplo.js"></script>
  ```

Un saludo.

EDITO:
No soy programador profesional y la web que estoy desarrollando tiene como objetivo aprender. Imaginaba que habían normas no escritas que "obligan" a usar la opción A o B que presentaba arriba. Parece que se trata más de una cuestión de gustos. Está claro que si el código JavaScript se va a usar en varios lugares de la web hay que llevar ese código a un fichero separado para poder reutilizarlo. No obstante me refería a código usado por un template/página html y solo uno.

Comment: Depende, si es un código pequeño y que no es tan relevante puede ir en el mismo web, de lo contrario es mejor hacerlo por ficheros separados ya que eso hace reutilizable tu código.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta debe ser cerrada, porque se basa principalmente en opiniones. Me di cuenta después de responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En django, lo mejor es separar el javascript de las plantillas. Por varias razones:

Los archivos de JavaScript, *son archivos estáticos* y su desarrollo y control siguen una ruta diferente de tu proyecto de Django.

Las plantillas de Django se van a dibujar cada vez que llames a la vista. No hay necesidad de hacer con los archivos de JavaScript. No hay necesidad de repetir cada vez el *renderizado* de los guiones de js...

Además, si los conviertes en archivos estáticos, puedes incluso mejorar el desempeño de tu sitio usando una CDN o el cacheo de archivos estáticos del servidor web.

Comment: +1 borro la mia, no lei que ocupaba Django.